# WordPress and Waypoint Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i'm trying to work Waypoints with WordPress and went through many
posts and tutorials on Google and for some reason it's still not working for me..

I put the waypoints.min.js and waypoints.js and the rest of the files in the download folder inside the js folder on my template's folder.

I loaded it from the admin and checked with the inspector and the links are good.
Here is my code-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('.slidingFacebook').hide();

        jQuery('.content').waypoint(function(direction) {
            if (direction == 'down') {
                jQuery('.slidingFacebook').fadeIn();
            }
            if (direction == 'up') {
                jQuery('.slidingFacebook').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried placing it in few different areas/pages and it still doesn't get to the waypoint function..

You can see it here- http://aviv.xcore.co.il/another-sample-post-show-website/

Thanks to all helpers!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving the code which calls the script files under the:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

in HTML.